# is the sum of positives definite matrix,still positive definite?

Tags: calculus

please give me hints on A = B + C. How can we show that A is positive definite?

Comment: $x^tAx=x^tBx+x^tCx$. Then $x^tBx\geq0$ because $B$ is positive definite and $x^tCx\geq0$  because $C$ is too.

Comment: More generally, can you show that the sum of two positive definite matrices is positive definite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associated hermitian form is $$x^HAx=x^HBx+\sum_{i=1}^n c_{ii}\overline{x}_ix_i\ge x^HBx>0$$ as soon as $x\ne 0$.